# How to get only administrative_area_level_2 from Google Geocoding API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I am attempting to get only the county name from a Google geolocation API result. Unfortunately, the county is not always in the same spot for the results so I need to grab it by an identifying key `administrative_area_level_2`

Here's my call:

```
$.getJSON( {
    url  : 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude + '&sensor=true',
    data : {
        sensor  : false
    },
    success : function( data, textStatus ) {
        var county = data.results[0].address_components[4].long_name;
        alert('County: ' + county);
    }
});
```

This works for the county I am in, but not for other counties because `address_components[4]` is not always the county. I did notice, however, that the county is always associated with `administrative_area_level_2`

Here's an example response:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Edge of Everglades Trail",
               "short_name" : "Edge of Everglades Trail",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Homestead",
               "short_name" : "Homestead",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Miami-Dade County",
               "short_name" : "Miami-Dade County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Florida",
               "short_name" : "FL",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "33031",
               "short_name" : "33031",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
...
```

How would I go about getting the "long_name" associated with `administrative_area_level_2` type?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to get `administrative_area_level_2` from address components array you can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) functions.

```
var filtered_array = data.results[0].address_components.filter(function(address_component){
    return address_component.types.includes("administrative_area_level_2");
}); 
var county = filtered_array.length ? filtered_array[0].long_name: "";
```

You can also search directly the `administrative_area_level_2` with reverse geocoding

```
$.getJSON( {
    url  : 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude + '&result_type=administrative_area_level_2',
    data : {
        sensor  : false
    },
    success : function( data, textStatus ) {
        var filtered_array = data.results[0].address_components.filter(function(address_component){
            return address_component.types.includes("administrative_area_level_2");
        }); 
        var county = filtered_array.length ? filtered_array[0].long_name: "";
        alert('County: ' + county);
    }
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ha, funnily enough this is the exact solution I came to. I was just about to add my own answer as a solution. Thanks.