# Google maps geocode API gives different hierarchy for postcode of UK who belongs to same town

Tags: google-maps

Google maps geocode API seems to be giving different heirarchy when two postcode which belongs to same town are given. For example, TW15 1AU and TW15 2UF.

TW15 1AU returns "Ashford, Greater London, England, United Kingdom" - https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJVz7Zd4xzdkgRzEM81pwMb1g

```
postal_code TW15 1AU    
route   Shield Road 
Shield Rd   
locality    Feltham political
postal_town Ashford 
administrative_area_level_2 Greater London  political
administrative_area_level_1 England political
country United Kingdom 
GB  political
```

TW15 2UF returns "Ashford, Surrey, England, United Kingdom" - https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJxW0-lv5zdkgRrJRpfMVlUO4:

```
postal_code TW15 2UF    
postal_town Ashford 
administrative_area_level_2 Surrey  political
administrative_area_level_1 England political
country United Kingdom 
GB  politica
```

Please note that administrative_area_level_2 gives two different values which I expect to be one.

The problem is that town "Ashford" now belongs to two different county which creates the problem. As far as location hierarchy is concerned, I understand that a town should fall in single county.

In summary, this causes many issues as location hierarchy given by Google is not that uniform.

Comment: google result for TW15 1AU: Postal code in Feltham, England, TW15 2UF: Postal code in Ashford, England, this is distance between them: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Ashford+TW15+2UF,+UK/Shield+Rd,+Feltham,+Ashford+TW15+1AU,+UK/@51.4337567,-0.4615862,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x487673fe963e6dc5:0xee5065c57c6994ac!2m2!1d-0.4658956!2d51.4344645!1m5!1m1!1s0x4876738c77d93e57:0x586f0c9cd63c43cc!2m2!1d-0.4432235!2d51.4357006

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @dkb, please refer links I have mentioned - also, I've updated response of API and you can notice that administrative_area_level_2 field is having totally different value and that's the problem. administrative_area_level_2 is equivalent to county in my opinion and the problem is that town "Ashford" now belongs to two different county which creates the problem. As far as location hierarchy is concerned, I understand that a town should fall in single county.

Comment: @lusitanica, I've updated the response of API, please refer. The problem here is administrative_area_level_2 is giving two different values which seems to be breaking hierarchy I expect as far as location is concerned. Please see my above comment which explains more.

Comment: `administrative_area_level_2` indicates a second-order civil entity below the country level. Within the United States, these administrative levels are counties. **Not all nations exhibit these administrative levels.**

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44603959/2987755

Comment: @dkb, problem is that administrative_area_level_2 gives different value for two postcode which belongs to same town.

Comment: Ask here: https://developers.google.com/maps/support/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the border between Greater London and Surrey cuts through Ashford according to Google Maps, resulting in one postcode lying in Surrey and one in Greater London. You could deal with this by collating your data into some form of table, filtering by postal town and if the counties are different you can correct the one that is wrong. I cannot provide an elegant coding solution to the problem as it would not be possible to tell which county is correct easily without human input.